# Solace how to find Ingress and Egress mesage count

Tags: solace

I am working on pipeline where JMS is sending messages to Solace queues and streaming job is consuming data from solace queues.

Here i want to plot Ingress/Egress message count on graph.
But there is huge difference between count.

here are message spool stats:

Number of ingress messages - 159479012
Number of egress messages - 222689956

How this is possible that egress count is higher?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all the details, one scenario that I can think of which can lead to a higher egress count compared to ingress is when you have more consumers than publishers. For example, if you have a publisher publishing messages on a topic and 10 consumers with 10 queues subscribing to that topic, that message will be delivered 10 times and hence, your egress count will be 10x than the ingress count.

Additionally, if you have messages being redelivered, they would also count towards your egress.

In case, this doesn't answer your question, you might want to post this question on Solace Community (https://solace.community/).